# Setting many variables written in a file to set in the environment of Shell at a time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, tcsh

I have written many variables to be set as environement variables in a file , how should i set them all at a time .

Sample Code in File :

```
BRUN_ABORT_DEPENDENT_JOBS_ON_NONZERO_EXIT="true"; export BRUN_ABORT_DEPENDENT_JOBS_ON_NONZERO_EXIT
BRUN_OWNER="zmansar"; export BRUN_OWNER
```

Comment: What stops you from just including the file with `. /path/to/file` ?

Comment: Same as Eugen, plus I would use the more readable/maintainable ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) `export BRUN_ABORT_DEPENDENT_JOBS_ON_NONZERO_EXIT="true";`